# Vue js -- accessing props through methods failed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-props

I am passing a proop in a component (component 1) to another one (component 2), the method related (which is in component 2 with passed/given props value) worked. Then i tried to put the method inside the component 1 and change the given value in the method to a internal dynamic proof, it stopped working.

It's for sure the problem of the way of accessing:

```js
wechat = document.getElementsByClassName(`this.iconsClassName`)[0].childNodes[2];
```

please help!

```
<template>
  <div :class="iconsClassName">
    <div :class="iconClassName" v-for="(icon, index) in icons" :key="index">
      <a :href="icon.mediaLink" target="_blank">
        <svg style="width:16px;height:16px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <path fill="#ffffff" :d="icon.icon" />
        </svg>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "mediaIcons",
  props: {
    iconsClassName: String,
    iconClassName: String,
    event: String
  },
  methods: {
    wechat() {
      let wechat = document.getElementsByClassName(this.iconsClassName)[0]
        .childNodes[2];
      wechat.addEventListener("click", alertWechat);
      function alertWechat() {
        alert("add me in weChat: eudora_neves");
        wechat.childNodes[0].removeAttribute("href");
      }
    },
  mounted: function() {
     this.wechat();
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: @Phil need help^^

Comment: Consider using `ref` attribute and then reference through `this.$refs`

Comment: @IVO GELOV, thanks very much, but i tried, no luck.

Comment: Can you show us how did you try ? I do not see any refs in your code.

Comment: on a somewhat unrelated context, the aim of frameworks like vue is remove the direct dom modifications such as `getElement`. Would it not be better approach to go with event binding in vue than getting element?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right, you want the `iconClassName` to be clickable?

```html
<div class="iconClassName">
<!-- content -->
</div>
```

For this you can use Vue's [v-on attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on). `@click="alertWechat"` should do the trick. Also, this would shorten your code and make it a bit more readable.

```
<template>
    <div :class="iconsClassName">
        <div 
            :class="iconClassName" 
            v-for="(icon, index) in icons" 
            :key="index" 
            @click="alertWechat"
        >
            <!-- content --> 
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "mediaIcons",
    props: {
        iconsClassName: String,
        iconClassName: String,
        event: String
    },
    methods: {
        function alertWechat() {
            //content
        }
    }
};
</script>
```